# When does a view outlet have to be set?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I have read through other answers on how to fix "view outlet was not set" exceptions, and understand how to set the file owner and view outlet. However, I can't understand when/why that exception is raised. How come I can get away with this, and it's not an issue?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewNib = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: nil)
    let myView = viewNib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! MyView

    self.view = myView
}
```

The `MyView` class is initialized with a nib, and the nib file itself does not have a file owner set, nor a view outlet, and it's fine. But other times, this doesn't work. I've tried to reproduce a specific case identifying when the exception is and isn't raised, but haven't been able to pin it down.

Comment: If you want to manually load the view & assign it as the `view` of your controller you can override loadView(). [See the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) for some clarifications regarding storyboards vs manual controller instantiation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Alladinian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199017/alladinian)'s comment helped. The relevant [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) are from the `loadView()` method:

> A view controller has an associated nib file if the nibName property returns a non-nil value, which occurs if the view controller was instantiated from a storyboard, if you explicitly assigned it a nib file using the init(nibName:bundle:) method, or if iOS finds a nib file in the app bundle with a name based on the view controller's class name.

For example, I made a nib with the name 'DuckView', and a view controller with the name 'DuckViewController', and Xcode automatically associated the two and expected the view outlet to be set. If the view outlet is not set, AND `loadView()` is not overridden, the exception is raised. Conversely, if either the view outlet IS set OR the `loadView()` method is implemented, it runs fine.